# What wild mammals could survive a nuclear winter?

Tags: post-apocalypse, survival, weapon-mass-destruction, nuclear-war, nuclear-winter

I'm writing a story that takes place after a nuclear winter that lasts for at least 25 years, and which caused much of the surviving population to become hunter-gatherers as a result of crop failure and the death of domesticated animals.  During the war biological weapons were also used, which released man-made diseases that could also infect non-human animals so some people and other animals died from man-made diseases in addition to the people and other animals that died from the effects of the nuclear weapons.

I'm curious about what mammals people would be able to hunt in the aftermath of the nuclear winter lasting 25 years and deadly diseases killing many of the mammals.

Comment: I'm delighted to see you're getting answers, but VTC:Needs More Details. What are the specific consequences of the nuclear winter? Does all the vegitation die? Do the seas die out? Does the global average temperature drop 30 degrees? Is sunlight reduced? Where is it affected? Are mountain tops affected? To what altitude? Where is the radiation and for how long? Without specific details concerning your nuclear winter (more than just duration) there is no predictable answers beyond "whatever you need for your story to be successful."

Comment: I think you misunderstand how nuclear winter would work. The first phase would be when the sun was blocked out by atmospheric ash. That can't really hang in the air for longer than 3-10 years, so I'm curious why you're specifying 25 years. During that period, EVERYTHING THAT NEEDS SUNLIGHT would die. Trees, grass, bushes, etc. Trees aren't equipped to hibernate for a decade. Everything that feeds off of them would mostly die off within a year, so herbivores and most birds. Also, vegans. Carnivores might last a couple of years. We'd be eating bugs that fed off of wood pulp.

Comment: Many fish live under water, some in total darkness as long as they have food and air they will survive and you can catch and eat them.  However, if you mess up your oceans that bad fish can't survive your going to stave to death.

Comment: If you want a realistic nuclear winter, model it after [the year without a summer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_Without_a_Summer).

Comment: And you have humans that survived that??

Comment: All post-apocalypticals have dogs. If they're not on the list; neither are we.

Answer (score 13):

Mostly the same sorts of mammals that survived the dinosaur holocaust. Rodent-like animals that live underground.

They can and do feed on roots, grubs, worms, etc, in tunnels, they make for themselves and are less affected by the weather. Frozen roots would keep plenty of sustenance without rotting, and underground life on a small scale would quite possibly thrive during this long winter.

Large animals and probably any wild mammals that had to live in the weather probably wouldn't last long at all. But rodents again like rats and mice might be fine since they cohabit with humans who can warm their dwellings and provide food.

Comment: Weather has very little to do with it, polar bears can live in cold weather just fine. The issue with large animals is that they need a lot of food. And to get the food they need to either eat a lot of plants (which are dead because of the lack of light) or eat a lot of other large animals (which are dead because of the lack of plants).

Comment: @vvotan weather has everything to do with it, because of the weather polar bears have no food. So anything living in the weather 's food sources have dried up.

Answer (score 10):

It is already suggested, but I would bet on small mammals that live underground and can eat anything they can find. After all, mammals were the survivors of the asteroid impact that killed the dinosaurs in a similar way to your plot. Immediately after the impact, there was a long winter due to the dust in the atmosphere that covered the Sun and thus killed plants and photosynthesis.

Specifically, I would consider creatures like rabbits, ground squirrels, rats, mice, or moles, who might be more protected from both the initial blast and the subsequent radiation and disease. These animals can feed on a wide variety of food sources, such as roots, insects, and carrion, which might still be available in a post-apocalyptic landscape.

Comment: being a generalist is important, they need to be able to eat whatever they can find. specialized feeders never survive such events. So no koala or panda for instance.

Answer (score 8):

The environment during and immediately after the nuclear winter will be harsh: few plants, scattered on large territories, which will be a small base for a food chain.

My guess is that the more opportunistic diet the mammal has, the higher the chances for it to survive because it will allow them to find food more often: carcasses, live animals, plants, and fruits, can all offer sustenance.

Also, body size will play a role: smaller bodies will have an advantage since they will require less intake to be kept alive, or alternatively will do more with the same minimal intake.

Raccoons and badgers come to mind as an example of mammals fitting both categories above.